# Filter a data.frame with another data.frame using index notation instead of subset

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

Given:

```
df  <- data.frame(rep = letters[sample(4, 30, replace=TRUE)], loc = LETTERS[sample(5:8, 30, replace=TRUE)], y= rnorm(30))

lookup <- data.frame(rep=letters[1:4], loc=LETTERS[5:8])
```

This will give me the rows in `df` that have rep,loc combinations that occur in `lookup`:

```
mdply(lookup, function(rep,loc){
  r=rep
  l=loc
  subset(df, rep==r & loc==l)
})
```

But I've [read](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset) that using `subset()` inside a function is poor practice due to scoping issues. So how do I get the desired result using index notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, `merge` seems to make the most sense to me:

```
merge(df, lookup)
#   rep loc          y
# 1   a   E  1.6612394
# 2   a   E  1.1050825
# 3   a   E -0.7016759
# 4   b   F  0.4364568
# 5   d   H  1.3246636
# 6   d   H -2.2573545
# 7   d   H  0.5061980
# 8   d   H  0.1397326
```

---

A simple alternative might be to `paste` together the "rep" and "loc" columns from `df` and from `lookup` and subset based on that:

```
df[do.call(paste, df[c("rep", "loc")]) %in% do.call(paste, lookup), ]
#    rep loc          y
# 4    d   H  1.3246636
# 10   b   F  0.4364568
# 14   a   E -0.7016759
# 15   a   E  1.6612394
# 19   d   H  0.5061980
# 20   a   E  1.1050825
# 22   d   H -2.2573545
# 28   d   H  0.1397326
```